# In Magento how do you get the database name?

Tags: database, magento

How do you get the database name from Magento?

I have seen functions like the one below that can get the table name.

> $orderItemTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_item');

I was hoping that there was some sort of function like this:

> Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getDatabaseName();

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Each module can specify it's own connection so you are right to go via a model.

```
$config = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order')->getConnection()->getConfig();
// $config is an array
$dbname = $config['dbname'];
```

If you're only interested in the default a slightly more efficient way might be:

```
$dbname = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources/default_setup/connection/dbname');
```

Comment: The model is the way I want to go but I get the following error when I try the above. Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order::getConnection()

Comment: Try it with `getReadConnection` or `getWriteConnection` instead.

Comment: Thats it, just for future reference for anyone reading this change $config = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order')->getConnection()->getConfig(); to Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order')->getReadConnection()->getConfig();

Answer (score 3):

To get the db name try

```
Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig('default_setup')->dbname;
```

See [How to get magento database details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992036/how-to-get-magento-database-details)

Answer (score 1):

It is always possible to get the current connection from Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'), quite specially if you use only one database.

```
$configArray = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->getConfig();
$db = $configArray['name'];
```

But it's comming with a zend adapter Zend_Config

```
// Create the object-oriented wrapper upon the configuration data
$config = new Zend_Config($configArray);
$db = $config->get('dbname');
```