# How to get magento database details

Tags: php, magento

I want to get magento's database configuration in any file within magento.

How do I do this?

Comment: Magento has a whole api of tools to use, learn to use them, then you don't need to have access to the database in every file.
http://www.magentoo.com/pub/magento-ebook-en.pdf is a nice start and expand on that

Comment: You shouldn't be using something like this.  The DB abstraction is really good in Magento, you should avoid using direct SQL.  You should look at Mage_Core_Model_Resource and Zend_Db_Select

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Magento connection details u find out to below method..........

```
require_once ('../app/Mage.php');
$app = Mage::app('default');

$config  = Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig('default_setup');

$dbinfo = array('host' => $config->host,
            'user' => $config->username,
            'pass' => $config->password,
            'dbname' => $config->dbname
);

$hostname = $dbinfo['host'];
$user = $dbinfo['user'];
$password = $dbinfo['pass'];
$dbname = $dbinfo['dbname'];
```